# VB6 copy/paste image over RDP

Tags: windows, vb6, remote-desktop

I have a problem where I'm using the Snipping Tool in Windows 7 to cut a bitmap and copy it to the clipboard on my local computer, then paste the clipboard bitmap in another application (VB6 legacy system) over RDP.

The problem is that the pasted image's rightmost 6 pixels (approx) get shifted to the left.

Is this a known issue of RDP? Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks,

Ivan

Comment: Is this behavior specific for your VB6 application, or you can reproduce it with something like MS Paint too? In the latter case your question may be a better fit for another StackExchange site.

Comment: Completely anecdotal I know but ... I have seen pixel shifts over RDP (my code was Delphi not VB)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the potential "bug", but before Windows' Snipping Tool, I used to use Snaggit which was great : http://www.techsmith.com/download/snagit/

If the issue lies in the clipboard (not sure how, but you never know) I'd also suggest looking at Ditto as it allows more flexibility interacting with the clipboard: http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/